# Retrofit Okhttp send dymanic request headers using interceptor?

Tags: android, retrofit, interceptor, okhttp

I am trying to sent dynamic headers using `Okhttp` `interceptor`, but the problem I am facing is when I am calling `setretrofitclient()` method at the same time, then the header sent for both request are same. This is happening because as okhttp interceptor went in background thread to execute the request but at the same time in `UI thread` header value gets changed because of which when okhttp send the request it send new updated header.

```
String header;

public String getHeader() {
    return header;
}

static RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface;;

public RetrofitInterface setretrofitclient(String header) {
    this.header = header;
    if (retrofit != null) {
         return retrofit;
    } else {
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("x-param", getHeader()).build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).baseUrl(url).client(httpClient.build()).build();
        retrofitInterface = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);
        return retrofitInterface;
    }
}
```

Can anyone please suggest me the design pattern how can I make this work for parallel requests.

Thanks.

Comment: You're returning an object from a method with a void return type, so this code cannot possibly compile.  Please post the actual code you're running.

Comment: @nasch that was a typo error.

Comment: Can you paste your corrected code?

Comment: Above code is actual code I have edited.

Comment: On the line that says "return retrofit" that still attempts to return an object from a method with void return type.  There's no way you ran this code.